# Liferay 7 Theme-Generator: Setting parent theme (baseTheme)

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-7

I have used the theme-generator to create a fresh theme.
Now I've created a second theme in the same directory and tried to set it's base/parent theme using `gulp extend` as explained on these pages:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-theme-tasks
https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/theme-gulp-tasks

After running the command and choosing option `1)` to extend the Base Theme , I get the following options:

1. Styled
2. Unstyled
3. Search globally installed npm modules (development purposes only)
4. Search npm registry (published modules)

No matter if I choose `3)` or `4)` I cannot find the theme package.

Do I really have to publish the theme to npm to be able to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this explanation I could achieve it using `npm link`:

- [npm link](http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears)

**Excerpt**:

> npm link: symbolic links to the rescue Fortunately npm provides a tool
>   to avoid this tedium. And it's easy to use. But there's a catch.
>
> Here's how it's supposed to work:
>
> 1. cd to src/appy
> 2. Run "npm link". This creates a symbolic link from a global folder to the src/appy folder.
> 3. cd to src/mysite
> 4. Run "npm link appy". This links "node_modules/appy" in this particular project to the global folder, so that "require" calls
>      looking for appy wind up loading it from your development folder,
>      src/appy.
>
> Mission accomplished... almost. If you installed Node in a typical
>   way, using MacPorts or Ubuntu's apt-get, then npm's "global" folders
>   are probably in a location shared system-wide, like /opt/local/npm or
>   /usr/lib/npm. And this is not good, because it means those "npm link"
>   commands are going to fail unless you run them as root.

**EDIT**: I was wrong to make a npm package out of it when you can also just require it locally. Even relative paths work. Example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-liferay-theme": "file:../My-Liferay-theme",
}
```